# Split mySQL column into many

Tags: mysql, sql

Ive got a MySQL column that has a set of number that are separated by spaces. There is about 330 spaces..... and they are not all in the same place ( for each set)
Is there a way I can do this automatically, like via a query?
Or is this possible in Microsoft SQL?

Edit 1: I'm afraid I haven't really tried anything, - not to sure what to do.
Here is an example of one of the sets of numbers

```
3 10 13 18 0 0 175 215 177 173 213 203 592 272 0 175 215 177 173 215 177 172 208 203 592
```

It's very repetitive.

Comment: Can you please put some snippets of what you are trying to say.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Fair warning:  Your schema violates first normal form.  That means this literally violates rule #1 in database design.  Databases are neither intended nor designed to handle data stored this way.  The correct way to do it is two tables with a many-to-one relationship.  Remember this pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a list of numbers, then use those numbers cross joined against your data with SUBSTRING_INDEX to get the individual fields.

Something like this:-

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SomeField, ' ', aNum + 1), ' ', -1)
FROM SomeTable
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT Units.aCnt + Tens.aCnt * 10 + Hundreds.aCnt * 100 AS aNum
    FROM
    (SELECT 0 AS aCnt UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) Units,
    (SELECT 0 AS aCnt UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) Tens,
    (SELECT 0 AS aCnt UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) Hundreds
) Sub1
WHERE LENGTH(SomeField) - LENGTH(REPLACE(SomeField, ' ', '')) >= aNum
```

SQL fiddle here:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c43a/4

Then find the person who designed the database table and explain to them about database design / normalisation / indexes.

EDIT - A way that can (just about) do this select, coping with the number of cols. It should return NULL for any col that doesn't exist for that row. Probably best used in a MySQL stored proc. It calculates the max number of cols and then generates some dynamic SQL to get those cols.

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(aField ORDER BY aNum)
INTO @sql
FROM
(
    SELECT (Units.aCnt + Tens.aCnt * 10 + Hundreds.aCnt * 100) AS aNum, CONCAT("IF(LENGTH(SomeField) - LENGTH(REPLACE(SomeField, ' ', '')) >= ", (Units.aCnt + Tens.aCnt * 10 + Hundreds.aCnt * 100), ", SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SomeField, ' ', ", (Units.aCnt + Tens.aCnt * 10 + Hundreds.aCnt * 100 + 1),"), ' ', -1), NULL) AS col",(Units.aCnt + Tens.aCnt * 10 + Hundreds.aCnt * 100)) AS aField
    FROM (SELECT MAX(LENGTH(SomeField) - LENGTH(REPLACE(SomeField, ' ', ''))) AS MaxDelim FROM SomeTable) Sub1,
    (SELECT 0 AS aCnt UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) Units,
    (SELECT 0 AS aCnt UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) Tens,
    (SELECT 0 AS aCnt UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) Hundreds
    WHERE Units.aCnt + Tens.aCnt * 10 + Hundreds.aCnt * 100 <= Sub1.MaxDelim
) Sub2;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', @sql,
                  '  FROM SomeTable
                    ');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

SQL fiddle for this:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a28ab2/2

Comment: thats great - only is it possible to put it into columns - not rows? Thanks

Comment: Not really, no as that would require a variable number of columns for each row (given it seems the number of delimiters varies, being about 330). You could do it manually (ie, specify each column individually using SUBSTRING_INDEX) but it would require a massive query and not really sure it would be usable.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks. Then is there a way to swap all the data in column A to row 1? Or should I ask another question? Thanks

Comment: Err, not sure I understand what you mean as you already have all the data in one row (and splitting it into separate columns would mean a variable number of columns per row unless the number is fixed). It might be better to expand your question to say what you want to use the data for once you have split the field up

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is that I have in one column, I've got about 500 of these long codes, and asit's difficult to separate them into columns, you did it into rows. So I wondered if it was possible to move all the data into the first row instead. Thanks

Comment: Afraid not in pure SQL, beyond pushing them all back into one column on the first row again (which would be pointless).

Comment: Just had a play and managed to do it. Will return each one as a column (but any rows with less fields will have null values in those final columns)